# How can i get information from few excel files into master file form a certain column?

Tags: excel, vba

Good Day! I have a code that copies all information from some files and inserts it into master file. I would like to modify it. Not to copy it but to sum up.

```
Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, r as Range
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

MyDir = "C:\Project\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx") 
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
 
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    For Each r in Rows
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        r.Rows.Hidden = False
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(5, 12), .Cells(Rws, 12))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) 'So here I copy infromation adn insert it.
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 1
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop
```

I cannot get my head around it. How do i sum up the same information and instead of copying it.
I dont mean sum up all the rows into master file, i would like to sum up same rows from different files into one master file.

Another thing, few files contain hidden rows, mayhaps im doing something wrong but those rows are still being hidden

> r.Rows.Hidden = False

does not seem to do the thing.
Any help would be much appreciated

Structure: All files are the same structure-wise, master-file is the same file but without any information in it, just the header. - first 4 rows[image]  Column 12 ("L") - is last one has the information i need, or will have i should say. Every Row has an ID that differ it from any other(column 1 - "A"). All documents all very similar, Items in those rows are the same, only difference is the quantity in the last column, which what i need to count. Master file: Row - Item - Quantity from All other files.

Comment: I see the point. Its quite the pickle for me. I would have to adjust the rest of the code accordingly. Its quite a lot. Is it possible to make this or something similar to it work?

Comment: To better answer your specific question, you'd have to give more information on how the data is structured. Do you have the same column names for the master file and the other files? How do you determine if 2 rows are the same? (ie. is there a column with a unique id or something?) Please edit your question to provide those details.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, r As Range
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

MyDir = "C:\Project\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
Do While MyFile <> ""
    
    Dim sWb As Workbook
    Set sWb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
    
    With sWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Rows.Hidden = False
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(Rws, 12))
    End With
    
    With Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim MatchingColumn As Range
        Set MatchingColumn = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    
        For Each r In rng.Rows
            If r.Cells(1, 1).Value2 <> vbNullString Then 'Ignoring empty rows
                
                'We find the row where the Ids matche
                Dim MatchingRowNb As Long
                MatchingRowNb = Application.Match(r.Cells(1, 1).Value2, MatchingColumn, False)
                    
                'We add the current value in the cell with the new value comming from the other file
                .Cells(4 + MatchingRowNb, 12).Value2 = .Cells(4 + MatchingRowNb, 12).Value2 + r.Cells(1, 12).Value2
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    sWb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: while running code, i have Error 13 Type Mismatch in this line 'MatchingRowNb = Application.Match(r.Cells(1, 1).Value2, MatchingColumn, False)'  When i was trying to cast into Application.WorksheetFunction.Match coming up with >Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match propertyof the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: MatchtinRowNb = 0 when i hover the mouse over it, 'r.Cell(1,1).Value2' does not show anything. I have looked up all documents, IDs are all present. Last row is total number of Items per document. Some of those are empty (we do not count them) Master File has total number of All items - can this be an issue, that those are empty?

Comment: Actually, the line of code that set MatchingRowNb to zero was optional, so I've removed it from my answer.

Comment: @TahirRuzbaev You could press Ctrl+G to make the [Immediate Window](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/) appear and then type `?r.Cell(1,1).Value2` in that window, press Enter and the value should appear.

Comment: @TahirRuzbaev Oh, so you have empty values in the data files but not the master file. Then you can add a simple if statement to take care of that. Please see edits made to the code. Note that I've also moved the MatchingColumn declaration outside the loop since it doesn't change between rows.

Comment: Still the same Error 13 Type Mismatch in the same line. [link](https://imgur.com/6zbww9S)

Comment: @TahirRuzbaev - What is the value of `r.Cell(1,1).Value2` ?